# How to run a shell function as a command in Ansible?

Tags: bash, shell, ansible, nvm

I'm using `nvm` (https://github.com/creationix/nvm), which is essentially a shell script that you source into your shell and then call, for example, `nvm install [version]`. But no matter how I try and call that function, ansible can't seem to find it.

I've tried using the `command` and `shell` modules. I've tried using `become` and `become_user`. I've tried using `sudo -iu` like in https://github.com/leonidas/ansible-nvm/blob/master/tasks/main.yml, but it doesn't work for me. It must be possible though since it works in that file.

How can I run any shell function in Ansible? In this case I've got a `source nvm.sh` in my .zshrc which allows me to execute `nvm` commands from the interactive shell fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll need to use the `shell` module, because you want to run shell commands, and you'll need to source in the `nvm` script into that environment.  Something like:

```
- shell: |
    source /path/to/nvm
    nvm install ...
```

Whether or not you use `become` depends on whether or not you want to run the commands as `root` (or another user).

Answer (score 0):

Here is my playbook for this:

```
- hosts: all
  vars:
    # https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm/releases
    nvm_version: "0.34.0"

    # https://github.com/nodejs/node/releases
    # "node" for latest version, "--lts" for latest long term support version,
    # or provide a specific version, ex: "10.16.3"
    node_version: "--lts"
  tasks:
  - name: Get_nvm_install_script | {{ role_name | basename }}
    tags: Get_nvm_install_script
    get_url:
      url: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v{{ nvm_version }}/install.sh
      dest: "{{ ansible_user_dir }}/nvm_install.sh"
      force: true

  - name: Install_or_update_nvm | {{ role_name | basename }}
    tags: Install_or_update_nvm
    command: bash {{ ansible_user_dir }}/nvm_install.sh

  - name: Install_nodejs | {{ role_name | basename }}
    tags: Install_nodejs
    shell: |
      source {{ ansible_user_dir }}/.nvm/nvm.sh
      nvm install {{ node_version }}
    args:
      executable: /bin/bash
```

Note the use of `executable: /bin/bash`, as `source` command is not available in all shells, so we specify `bash` because it includes `source`

As an alternative to `source` you can use the dot:

```
  - name: Install_nodejs | {{ role_name | basename }}
    tags: Install_nodejs
    shell: |
      . {{ ansible_user_dir }}/.nvm/nvm.sh
      nvm install {{ node_version }}
```